# Flex Localization: refresh DataProvider values

Tags: apache-flex, localization

I have a ToggleButtonBar with a DataProvider setup like this:

```
   <mx:ToggleButtonBar itemClick="clickHandler(event);" selectedIndex="0">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:String>{resourceManager.getString('dashboard','daily')}</mx:String>
        <mx:String>{resourceManager.getString('dashboard','monthly')}</mx:String>
        <mx:String>{resourceManager.getString('dashboard','quarterly')}</mx:String>
        <mx:String>{resourceManager.getString('dashboard','yearly')}</mx:String>
    </mx:dataProvider>
   </mx:ToggleButtonBar>
```

To switch locale to Chinese, I have a combobox with this handler:

```
resourceManager.localeChain = "zh_CN";
```

My problem is that on locale change, while the labels for all the other controls on the screen dynamically reload for the new locale, the `dataProvider` values don't refresh. 
I can manually reset them in code, but is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would abstract out the data for your data provider into a bindable variable, then just reset the data provider when you change locals.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        myArray:Array = new Array(
              [resourceManager.getString('dashboard','daily')]
            , [resourceManager.getString('dashboard','monthly')]
            , [{resourceManager.getString('dashboard','quarterly')]
            , [resourceManager.getString('dashboard','yearly')]);

    ]]>
</mx:Script>


<mx:ToggleButtonBar itemClick="clickHandler(event);" 
selectedIndex="0" id="myToggleButtonBar" dataprovider="{myArray}" />
```

Then you can just say

```
myToggleButtonBar.dataProvider = myArray;
```

after you swap the locals and it should work.

Disclaimer, there may be some minor errors in my code, I obviously am not able to test it and I don't have flex builder available right now to even check my syntax so I hope I didn't make any spelling mistakes.  But this should get you in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you make a getter bindable to a custom event for ex: "langChange"

```
[Bindable("langChange")]
public function get dataProviderToggleB():ArrayCollection
{
    var arr :ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    arr.addItem(resourceManager.getString('dashboard','daily'));
    arr.addItem(resourceManager.getString('dashboard','monthly'));

    return arr; 
}
```

and in your "resourceManager.localeChain" setter you dispatch:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("langChange"));
```

and you can used like this:

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar dataProvider="{dataProviderToggleB} itemClick="clickHandler(event);" selectedIndex="0">
```

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep 'daily', ... in your array and use a labelFunction to translate the label.
When the resourceManager sends a change event you should do a combo.labelFunction = labelFunction

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add brackets around each element in the dataProvider array, that way it gets parsed correctly.  Note that this also binds correctly to locale changes in flex, no custom event dispatching is needed.

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar itemClick="clickHandler(event);" selectedIndex="0" 
  dataProvider="{[ (resourceManager.getString('dashboard','daily')),
                   (resourceManager.getString('dashboard','monthly')),
                   (resourceManager.getString('dashboard','quarterly')), 
                   (resourceManager.getString('dashboard','yearly')) ]}">
</mx:ToggleButtonBar>
```